# Is there a sample JavaScript code showing how to generate a monero address from a string of characters?

Tags: address, javascript

I'm looking to make a JavaScript brain wallet generator for Monero. Is there a JavaScript library to create Monero addresses?

Answer (score 7):

There is Javascript code to generate Monero addresses from an arbitrary string, yes. See https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/monero-wallet-generator/tree/master. This page contains code originally from MyMonero (https://mymonero.com/).

The general idea is to hash the string (preferably using a KDF), and use the resulting hash as the spend key. The view key is obtained from the spend key.

Comment: Is there a sample code somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I included a link in the post you're replying to. The repo contains a single HTML page, which has the code you're looking for.the `genwallet` function, from which you can look at what it calls (which is also in that same file).

Comment: I found the line: https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/monero-wallet-generator/blob/master/monero-wallet-generator.html#L10950 --- but is there an example code of how to use it?